# A sum of money amounts to Rs.49400 in 3 years and Rs.50400 in 5 years > at the same rate of simple interest.

Tags: linear-algebra, finance

> A sum of money amounts to Rs.49400 in 3 years and Rs.50400 in 5 years
>   at the same rate of simple interest. Find rate of interest per annum.

This question was asked in Railway Exam.
Source: question number 25 in http://indread.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/rrc_englishpaper_8-12-2013-2.pdf

But the answer given is 8%. I think it is wrong.

**My Approach**
$$ 
P(1+3R/100)=49400 \\
P(1+5R/100)=50400
$$
Solving these 2 gives answer near to 1%.

Is it correct

Comment: Number 45 also is incorrectly marked. A speedometer measures instantaneous speed, not acceleration. Number 49 likewise is incorrectly marked. Numbers 47 and 48 are absurd: momentum is mass _times_ velocity, not a measure of one or the other alone; and Newton's 2nd law is a relationship among force, acceleration, and mass, not a measure of any one of those quantities alone. In both cases two equally good (and equally bad) choices are given, and the answer key arbitrarily chooses one.

Comment: The formula for interest looks strange to me. Did you add the interest instead of multiplying them? (e.g. $(1+R/100)^5$). Oh, did not realize this thread was so old...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. I get the same with my calculation.

Simple interest amount over the $2$ year 
period is

$SI_2 = 50400- 49400 = 1000$

Simple interest for $5$ years is then

$SI_5 = 5*\frac{1000}{2} = 2500$

Principal amount is then

$P = 50400 - 2500 = 47900$

And the rate $I$ of interest per annum:

$I = (SI \times 100)/(P \times T)$

$I =  (2500 \times 100)/(47900 \times 5) \approx 1\%$